# "Payload" option on Facebook Bots buttons

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

[Facebook Send API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference) mentions a "payload" type you can set for buttons on the Generic Response Template. However, they don't say how it works, other than:

> For postback buttons, this data will be sent back to you via webhook

But how is it sent back? I don't receive any messages when I click the payload button. Has anyone successfully used it?

Comment: did you subscribed to messaging_postbacks option while setting up web-hook for messenger bot..?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested it and it works for me. The payload of a button acts like the value on a html button. This means it's not visible to the user but it's the value that's send back to you.

If you create a button like that:

```
'attachment': {
    'type': 'template',
    'payload': {
        'template_type': 'button',
        'text': 'This is the description',
        'buttons': [
             {
                 'type': 'postback',
                 'title': 'This is the visible text',
                 'payload': 'This is the value you get back'
             }
        ]
 }
```

A callback including a payload looks like that:

```
{'timestamp': 1461697120850, 'postback': {'payload': 'this is the value you get back'}, 'recipient': {'id': xxxxxxxx}, 'sender': {'id': xxxxxxxx}}
```

Comment: how to capture it's value in php ?

Comment: @runningmark `if(isset($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['quick_reply'])){
 $payload_txt = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['quick_reply']['payload'];`

Comment: Have you test these lines ? I tried it it's not working

Comment: During debugging I log all requests received into a textfile:

file_put_contents("testfile.txt", 
                json_encode( $input ) . PHP_EOL,
                FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Comment: Good for viewing request structure

Comment: Is anyone able to see docs on the maximum allowed size of the payload. Can't find it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_postbacks)

Comment: how can i add custom keys to the default button array

'attachment': {
    'type': 'template',
    'payload': {
        'template_type': 'button',
        'text': 'This is the description',
        'buttons': [
             {
                 'type': 'postback',
                 'title': 'This is the visible text',
                 'payload': 'This is the value you get back'
                 'custom_field': number
             }
        ]
 }

Answer (score 5):

When you click the Button a POST message is sent to your `/webhook`.

You have to handle the payload like this:

```
app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
  messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
  for (i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
    event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i];
    sender = event.sender.id;
    if (event.message && event.message.text) {
      text = event.message.text;
      // Handle a text message from this sender
    } else if (event.postback && event.postback.payload) {
      payload = event.postback.payload;
      // Handle a payload from this sender
    }
  }
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

This code snippet is from the Getting Started Guide from Facebook except for the `else if` where you can react on the payload.

Comment: hi, how can we implement with php, unable to find perfect way to get the value of payload

Answer (score 1):

This is how you read back the payload:

```
$payload = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['postback']['payload'];
```